# Camel routes shutdown after task complete

Tags: apache-camel

I have a batch job which I have implemented with apache camel.
I don't want a long running process but a pure batch job.

Currently as the last step of the route I call a processor which does a System.exit() and camel shuts down after default 5 minutes of timeout.

```
    <route id="dataFetch">
        <from uri="direct:dataFetch"/>
        <split>
            <simple>${body}</simple>
            <to uri="bean:dataFetchProcessor"/>
            <to uri="direct:dataPersist"/>
        </split>
        <to uri="bean:stopAndExitProcessor"/>
        <stop/>
    </route>
```

This solution works for me but feels iffy.
Any suggestions how to do it right way?

Comment: Hi @nishant, may I ask you if you have ever noticed if without that "bean:stopAndExitProcessor" the Camel thread behind <split> remained forever live? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I would be more tempted to use `CamelContext.stop()` method.

Here's an example of how to do it in a processor:

```
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.getContext().stop();
    }
```

Stopping the context in this way will allow in-flight messages to complete. If your route is still consuming and prevents shutdown, you may need to stop the route first (e.g. via `controlbus`).

Comment: Ah! Taking your hint I did following instead of calling stopAndExitProcessor:             

<to uri="controlbus:language:simple?async=true&amp;action=${camelContext.stop()}"/>

It seems like I do not get the 5 minutes timeout to shutdown now and also it lets in flight exchanges to complete. (Will test more)

Comment: Using controlbus to shutdown camelContext does not exit the jvm since I have started camel using main.run()

Eventually the best way I could do is to call main.stop() which gracefully shutdown camel and exits the jvm as well